# Docker Log Copy

Tags: docker

I need make a copy from container log and forward to Graylog. However, I need that the logs continue in Docker. In other words:
I need do:

```
docker log -f <some_container>
```

and see the same logs in graylog.

Is it possible to perform this task?

Answer (score 1):

`docker log -f container`, It just tails the end of logs file.

If you want to get pull logs of container you can get the logs to file path from container.

```
docker inspect <some_container> | grep LogPath
```

You will get the log file path, now you can read the full logs or you can use tail as well.

```
for container in $(docker ps -q); do echo $container; docker inspect $container | grep LogPath; done
```

This will return logs file path of All running container.

> To send container logs to a server that supports Graylog Extended Log
>   Format (GELF), such as Graylog or Logstash, pass the gelf log driver
>   and options as follows:

```
docker run \
    --log-driver=gelf \
    --log-opt gelf-address=udp://host:port \
    --log-opt tag="example" \
    --log-opt labels=label1,label2 \
    --log-opt env=env1,env2 \
    my_container_image
```

[docker-log-drivers](https://www.joyent.com/blog/docker-log-drivers)

Comment: First, tkz for answer. But sorry, byt my problem is more complex. I use kubernetes, and some times I need get the log in cmd:

$ kubectl logs -f POD

And in same time, I need that the same log be forward to graylog. If I put the gelf drive for example, all logs will be send to the graylog. In this case, I cant look my logs in cmd. This is my problem, how make a copy!!!

In time, is a production enviroment and is impossible I do

$docker inspect | grep LogPath

to all container instances. There is some way that make a copy, or put two drives in dockerd?

Tkz a lot.

Comment: Then other way is to sync or mount  the log directory

Answer (score 0):

First, tkz for answer. But sorry, byt my problem is more complex. I use kubernetes, and some times I need get the log in cmd:

```
$ kubectl logs -f POD
```

And in same time, I need that the same log be forward to graylog. If I put the gelf drive for example, all logs will be send to the graylog. In this case, I cant look my logs in cmd. This is my problem, how make a copy!!!

In time, is a production environment and is impossible I do

```
$ docker inspect <some_container> | grep LogPath
```

to all container instances. There is some way that make a copy, or put two drives in dockerd?

Tkz a lot.